# How to vertically center a container of flexible heights only given a padding-bottom?

Tags: html, css

I created a relativley flexible layout width flexible heights using the padding-bottom approach.

Now i really struggle to center the block floating-item (see FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/nZmr5/) vertically. Does someone has an idea to make that happen without javascript?

Here is my structure:

```
 <HTML>

<HEAD>
<TITLE>My new webpage</TITLE>
<style>
body, html {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:green;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.floating-item{
    padding-top:0;
    margin:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:0.1%;
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;
    border: 1px black solid;
}
.item{
background-color:white;
float:left;
width:20%;
padding-bottom:1%;
margin-left:4%;
margin-top:1%;
}


</style>


</HEAD>

<BODY>
<div class="floating-item">
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to vertically align the container you need to set the height of `body` to 100% and give to `.floating-item` a `margin-top:50%` and `bottom:50%` (or `top:-50%`). See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nZmr5/3/embedded/result/

This method centers vertically your container to the body but it doesn't update the position when resizing the browser because the height of your container changes on the fly. If you need a more reliable alignment you need to give a fixed height to `.floating-item` unless you're happy with the alignment every time your page loads.

Comment: I tried your demo and set the height of `.item` to various values.  The vertical centering does not work.  This is a tricky problem...

Comment: It works fine every time you refresh the page. See the 2nd paragraph of my answer.

Comment: thanks for your help! hmm after resizing and reload this doesn't work for me...the tricky thing is the approach with the bottom padding which looks for the width of the window...any further idea?

Comment: Do you accept a jQuery solution or just pure CSS? I don't think this will be easy just with CSS unless we implement the HTML structure in a different way.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what u are looking for?

```
.floating-item{
    padding-top:0;
    margin:0;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:0.1%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:red;
    border: 1px black solid;
}
```

Comment: I guess he wants the group of items centered vertically

Comment: @Brainfeeder floating-item is container, centered container means centered group of contained items. Please, correct me if going wrong way.

Comment: @MiroslavStopka You are correct, unless he needs the container element to fit the whole page and only the items to be centered. This was not clear in the question.

Comment: @Brainfeeder That is truth.